# How to make i18n settings async Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

Active langauges and translations are coming from API. I need to find a way to set up i18n to be async.
So first of all I'll fetch available languages for this website from API, after that I would detect current langauge from prefix/cookie and fetch only It's translations and after that I would listen to nuxtApp.$i18n.onBeforeLanguageSwitch so i can fetch translations if needed and add it to i18n object

**Edited**

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ru', 'es', 'de', 'fi', 'sv', 'fr', 'it', 'br'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    strategy: 'prefix',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      redirectOn: 'root',
    },
  },
```

`plugins/i18n.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {

  useAsyncData('directory_translations', async () => {
    const data = await DirectoryApi.getAllDirectories()
    const directory = DirectoryService.createDirectoryObject(data)
    const translationsData = await DirectoryApi.getTranslations(directory.languages[nuxtApp.$i18n.locale.value].ID)
    const translations = DirectoryService.createTranslationsObject(translationsData, directory)

    nuxtApp.$i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(nuxtApp.$i18n.locale.value, translations)
    // this is working also, but somehow messages are created from scratch on client side and data is lost
    useState('directory', () => directory)
    useState('translations', () => translations)

  })

  nuxtApp.$i18n.onBeforeLanguageSwitch = async (oldLocale, newLocale, isInitialSetup, nuxtApp) => {
    // This works
    const directory = useState('directory') as Ref<Directory>
    const translationsData = await DirectoryApi.getTranslations(directory.value.languages[newLocale].ID)
    const translations = DirectoryService.createTranslationsObject(translationsData, directory.value)
    nuxtApp.$i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(newLocale, translations)
  }
})
```

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

const {messages} = useI18n()

</script>

<template>

<div>
 {{ JSON.stringify(messages) }} 
</div>

</template>
```

Everything works fine on server side, On recieved html (from server) i can see message list, but seems like i18n reruns itself on client ones more and my messages are gone

Comment: Nuxt 3 have SSR functionality, why you not first check what language user wants and translate it?

Comment: Does this help you? https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/lazy.html

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? How is your nuxt config looking so far?

Comment: I know what language user wants/needs (i18n detects it), I need way to fetch translations on server and send to the client. Client side is already done

Comment: Do that a build time, so that it's ready when requested by the client side.

Comment: Then i have to rebuild project on every added/deleted translation, no? if you mean to add it in nuxt.config.ts

Comment: Where are you doing your translations? By hand in the JSON files or using a platform like lokalise? For the first one, you'll push your code and it will rebuild. For the second one, webhooks will be in charge of redoing that. It also depends if you're using SSG or SSR, the latter don't even need to be rebuilt + it depends of the frequency of your updates.

Comment: It's fully SSR. There is custom admin panel that have translations panel, where you can add/delete/update it, so it could change very often and that's why I can't do it on application build time, I need to do it on server before i build HTML, and I'm not that familiar with Nuxt yet and can't find place where I can do that

Comment: If it's SSR, it will be done each time the user requests a page (initial render, before client side navigation) so not a build time.

Comment: Usually we import `$t` if I'm not mistaken. `messages` are all the messages no? Hence some locale may be needed. But using `$t` is probably the way to go overall.

Comment: I did it, problem was i was using useAsynData. Made plugin async and used node fetch to get data. everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP fixed the issue by using an async plugin + using `node-fetch` to get the data (rather than `useAsyncData`).

I also recommend that you give a try to that one (works everywhere): https://github.com/unjs/ohmyfetch